# expires header in w3 total cache

Tags: headers, plugin-w3-total-cache

Hello i read about expires header and as i understand it's very important but it's dangers because visors will not see the changes that happen on my site, so my question can enable expires header and when make new changes then go to w3 total cache and empty all caches ? this will solve the problem to me be sure that all visitors will see the new updates ?

Comment: Joe It will not solve problem as expires headers added locally in browser so it will still load old files stored at cache in browser. For that you can try this plugin called [Add Expires Headers](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-expires-headers/) and use 0 days as Expiry time for format of files you want to update at users browsers. But make sure your server supports mod_expire module before try because some of server mostly shared have not support for this.